# Twilio PHP API Librarie: Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, file-get-contents, twilio

I installed Official Twilio PHP API Librarie via composer ( "twilio/sdk": "~3.12" ).

When I trying use API ( for example send an SMS ) using Test Credentials I get the error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   ..vendor/twilio/sdk/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php line 62

If I trying send SMS in terminal using curl - everything is OK.

How it may be fixed without editing Twilio PHP API Librarie code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I found this happened when you don't have the curl bindings for PHP. Try [recompiling PHP with curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) or [installing the php5-curl package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: philnash, thanks! Yes, "apt-get install php5-curl" helps in this situation. But why? Twilio using file_get_contents(), not curl_exec()...

Comment: I'm no PHP developer, I'm afraid, so I'm not in the best position to look into why right now. I do want to see it fixed, or at least find out from someone with a bit more experience how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I fixed the problem. Edit `Twilio.php`, right above `verify_peer`, add this line:

```
'cafile' => '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
```

This fix worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 running PHP 5.5.9.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to solve this for half a day. Tried everything under the sun and finally your solution was the only thing that worked.