# Twilio: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_HttpStreamException' with message 'Unable to connect to service'

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I am using this code in PHP to list SMS messages received to a certain number:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('twilio/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = ""; 
$token = ""; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    'To' => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] 
)); 

foreach ($messages as $message) { 
    echo "<tr><td>" . $message->from . "</td><td>" . $message->date_sent . "</td><td>" . $message->body . "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

but it is outputting this error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 67

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 67

Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC049b65c32bd0cad6a229b44719ac6116/Messages.json?Page=0&PageSize=50&To=%2B16466635449): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 67

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_HttpStreamException' with message 'Unable to connect to service' in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php:70 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_HttpStream->__call('get', Array) #1 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_HttpStream->get('/2010-04-01/Acc...') #2 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio.php(260): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio.php(236): Base_Services_Twilio->_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...', 1) #4 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(125): Base_Services_Twilio->retrieveData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array) #5 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(179): Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPage(0, 50, Array, NULL) #6 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPageGenerator(0, 50, Array, NULL) #7 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/AutoPagingIterator.php(104): call_user_func_array(Array, Array in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/HttpStream.php on line 70
```

**Update**

Installed `php5-curl` as suggested by @philnash and restarted.

New error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain' in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php:119 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->__call('get', Array) #1 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_TinyHttp->get('/2010-04-01/Acc...') #2 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio.php(260): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio.php(236): Base_Services_Twilio->_makeIdempotentRequest(Array, '/2010-04-01/Acc...', 1) #4 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(125): Base_Services_Twilio->retrieveData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array) #5 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(179): Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPage(0, 50, Array, NULL) #6 [internal function]: Services_Twilio_ListResource->getPageGenerator(0, 50, Array, NULL) #7 /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/AutoPagingIterator.php(104): in /var/www/temp-sms.com/twilio/Services/Twilio/TinyHttp.php on line 119
```

Comment: That's weird, are you able to make any other outbound API calls (to Twilio or any other service) from your server?

Comment: @philnash Hi. I missed pasting the warning messages also. I have added these now. Do these help at all? I'm brand new to Twilio and little API experience (anywhere). I'm running this on a Linode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio PHP API Librarie: Warning: file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313186/twilio-php-api-librarie-warning-file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313186/twilio-php-api-librarie-warning-file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with), so I have replicated the answer here. However, it may be better for StackOverflow's rules to close this as a duplicate.

--

I found this happened when you don't have the curl bindings for PHP. Try [recompiling PHP with curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php) or [installing the php5-curl package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-curl-in-php5).

Let me know if that helps at all.

**[edit]**

If you find you are now getting an error regarding self signed certificates you will want to follow the advice available in the [Twilio PHP FAQ](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions).

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Did you ever find out "why?" (as the comments there). Thanks.

Comment: In terms of why `curl` works over `file_get_contents` I don't know exactly. I can tell you that the Twilio library supports PHP environments with and without curl, however it seems that the curl version is better suited most of the time. You could try the other answer on that page, that sets the certificates for `file_get_contents`. I'm still no PHP developer though, so I can't answer in depth I'm afraid.

Comment: Installed `php5-curl` as suggested and restarted but now I'm getting a new error message.

Comment: Updated my answer, check out the [FAQ on the Twilio PHP library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/docs/faq.rst#ssl-validation-exceptions).